# Loading ImageIcon from JAR or file system

Tags: java, eclipse, image, resources, jar

I have a simple program that needs to display images.
I know how to do this running the code from Eclipse and I know how to do it running from a JAR file, but I'd like a solution that works in both cases.

Eclipse project is as such:

```
- Project (java)
  - src
    - controller
      - Main.java
    - ui
      - Display.java
  - images
    - image.jpg
```

The code snippet that works from within Eclipse:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/image.jpg);
```

The one that works for a JAR (all in a single JAR file):

```
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("/images/image.jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
```

What would I need to change in order to get a single piece of code that works in both situations?

Comment: Have you tried the second attempt in both situations? that might just answer your own question for you (and save you the time of having to wait for answers here)!

Comment: <tap, tap, tap...> Hello?  Is this mic on?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. Yes, obviously I tried both code snippets in both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the `images` folder inside the `src` folder, and Eclipse will copy the images into the target folder (`bin` or `classes`, generally), which will make them available from the classpath, just as if they were in your jar in the released version of your app.

`getResource()` doesn't look in a jar. It looks in the classpath of the classloader. Whether the image is in a jar or not is thus not important. It must be in the classpath. And obviously the target folder of eclipse (`bin` or `classes`, generally) is in the runtime classpath of the app when you launch it from Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Moving the `images` folder inside `src` was indeed the solution. My second code snippet worked unchanged in both Eclipse and when run from a Jar.