# Strange behavior of Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource() in executable jar

Tags: java, classloader, embedded-resource, executable-jar

I understand from [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)
and from own code, that

```
getClass().getResource("/path/image.png")
```

is identical to

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/image.png")
```

The posting [Cannot read an image in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249613/cannot-read-an-image-in-jar-file) shows an issue where using

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/image.png")
```

in an executable jar file returns null, while

```
getClass().getResource("/path/image.png")
```

returns the correct URL.

`Since Class.getResource()` delegates to `ClassLoader.getResource()` after removing the leading slash, I would expect that these calls are identical, but obviously they are not in this case. Even when a special class loader is attached to the particular class, it should still be the same one for each call, again resulting in the same behavior.

So, the question is: **are there any obvious circumstances under which the following
code returns null for the first call but the proper URL for the second call?**

```
package com.example;

import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceTest {

   public void run() {
      URL iconUrl1 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/image.png");
      System.out.println("ClassLoader.getResource(\"path/image.png\"): " + iconUrl1);

      URL iconUrl2 = getClass().getResource("/path/image.png");
      System.out.println("Class.getResource(\"/path/image.png\"): " + iconUrl2);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ResourceTest app = new ResourceTest();
      app.run();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you reproduced this behavior or is this question just based on the one you linked? Try to provide an SSCCE, then people will be able to answer this question.

Comment: Unfortunately it is just based on the one I linked - I was not able to reproduce it. I would have definitely posted an SSCCE if I could :), my hope is to get some feedback through this question to be able to write code which reproduces such an issue. I already stepped into getClass().getResource() with the debugger, and I see the algorithm mentioned in the first link above, but I have no idea in which cases  the behavior described in the linked question could occur.

Comment: Add a working example please. I looked in the java.lang classes source and javadoc for info, but I got the same information as you already mentioned.

Comment: @gyabraham I have added a working sample. Any idea how to break it? (sounds like a strange question on SO ;) )

Comment: Q: Any idea how to break it? A: Yes.  If you want "null" for one but not the other, all you should have to do is put your "class" files in a different directory than your "classloader root".  In other words, all you should have to do is introduce a package (which you should be doing anyway).  My example does this on my machine: 1/2 the cases are "SUCCESS", and 1/2 are "NULL".  I'm using JDK 1.6.  I understand when you run *my same code*, you get *all* "SUCCESS" and no "NULL".  Q: Is that correct?

Comment: Q: Is that correct? A: No. See http://pastebin.com/eMgAiLNy - I get the same output like you. Remember: my question is all about lines 2 and 3 of your output. They both give SUCCESS, both in your and in my application. Which is the expected behavior. Q: Is it possible by some subtle mechanism that ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt): returns null, while Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) returns SUCCCESS?

Comment: @Andreas - So I guess the answer to your question is "No": 1) We're completely clear on the difference between ClassLoader.getResource() and Class.getResource(), correct? 2) Your sample output matches my sample output, for both "SUCCESS" and for "null", correct?  3) This matches what we'd *expect*, correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) Yes. 4) Conclusion: Either we oversaw something, or something different caused the "solution" described in the linked question to work. I think we can not currently prove one or the other. If you like, phrase your points 1) 2) 3) as answer and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @AndreasFester I have a different scenario with regards to output. Both ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt) and Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) giving me SUCCESS when run in Eclipse. But both of them returning NULL when run from a executable jar on windows machine. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I thought this question was already asked and answered!

> - [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and
>     ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)
>
> `getClass().getResource()` searches relative to the .class file while
>   `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` searches relative to the
>   classpath root.

If there's an SSCCE here, I don't understand why it doesn't

1) Show the directory organization in the .jar, and...

2) Take package into consideration

Q: What (if anything) hasn't already been answered by [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource) (and the links it cites)?

=========================================================================

I'm still not sure what isn't clear, but this example might help:

```
/*
  SAMPLE OUTPUT:
  ClassLoader.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt): NULL
  Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt): SUCCESS

  ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt): SUCCESS
  Class.getResource(subdir/readme.txt): NULL
 */
package com.so.resourcetest;

import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceTest app = new ResourceTest ();
    }

    public ResourceTest () {
        doClassLoaderGetResource ("/subdir/readme.txt");
        doClassGetResource ("/subdir/readme.txt");
        doClassLoaderGetResource ("subdir/readme.txt");
        doClassGetResource ("subdir/readme.txt");
    }

    private void doClassLoaderGetResource (String sPath) {
        URL url  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(sPath);
        if (url == null)
            System.out.println("ClassLoader.getResource(" + sPath + "): NULL");
        else
            System.out.println("ClassLoader.getResource(" + sPath + "): SUCCESS");
    }

    private void doClassGetResource (String sPath) {
        URL url  = getClass().getResource(sPath);
        if (url == null)
            System.out.println("Class.getResource(" + sPath + "): NULL");
        else
            System.out.println("Class.getResource(" + sPath + "): SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Here's the corresponding directory tree.  It happens to be an Eclipse project, but the directories are the same regardless if it's Eclipse, Netbeans ... or a .jar file:

```
C:.
├───.settings
├───bin
│   ├───com
│   │   └───so
│   │       └───resourcetest
│   └───subdir
└───src
    ├───com
    │   └───so
    │       └───resourcetest
    └───subdir
```

The file being opened is "subdir/readme.txt"

---

ADDENDUM 11/9/12:

Hi -

I copied your code verbatim from github, re-compiled and re-ran:

```
ClassLoader.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt): NULL
Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt): SUCCESS
ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt): SUCCESS
Class.getResource(subdir/readme.txt): NULL
```

If that's *not* the output you're getting ... I'm baffled.

For whatever it's worth, I'm running:

- Eclipse Indigo (it shouldn't matter)
- Running inside the IDE (it shouldn't matter if it's filesystem or .jar, inside or outside an IDE)
- My JRE is 1.6 (if anything, this is probably the biggie)

Sorry we haven't been able to resolve what I *thought* was a straightforward issue :(

---

ADDENDUM 11/21/12 (Andreas):

Since there was no recent activity on this question, I would like to summarize what we found:

- From our common understanding, the answer to the above question is: **"No, it is not possible that `Class.getResource("/path/image.png")` returns a valid URL, while `ClassLoader.getResource("path/image.png")` returns null"**:

  - We're completely clear on the difference between ClassLoader.getResource() and Class.getResource()
  - Our sample outputs match, for both "SUCCESS" and for "null"
  - The sample outputs match what we'd expect
  - Conclusion: Either we oversaw something, or something different caused the "solution" described in the linked question to work. I think we can not currently prove one or the other.

Comment: The question to which I still have not seen an answer is: How can `getClass().getResource("/path/image.png");` return a URL while `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/image.png");` returns
null in an executable jar file (assumed the same packaging). My understanding is "It's not possible, at least not in a vanilla standard JDK/JRE environment". In which case the OP of the originating (linked) question would have a completely different root issue. Otherwise, show me how to package my sample code to achieve this behaviour :)

Comment: Your sample is completely valid and is not different from my understanding and from the output of my sample. Still, the question is: is there any way to package this into an executable jar file, such that `Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt)` returns `SUCCESS`. but `ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, darn it!!!!  That's exactly what my first example does!!!!  Please look at the sample output - or run it yourself.  In your own directory, or your own .jar - they're completely equivalent!!!!  Please ... look ... *AGAIN*!  And please remember: 1) "package" implies "directory paths", 2) the "absolute path" for the loader is one thing, 3) the "absolute path" for a "class" is, dependent on package, a *DIFFERENT* thing!!!!

Comment: @Andreas - Q: Do you see how the example return "SUCCESS" for Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) and "null" for ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt)?  Have you tried it yourself yet?  With a .jar file?

Comment: No, when I run your sample, ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt) does not return "null", but SUCCESS, see http://pastebin.com/eMgAiLNy. For both, run from filesystem or executable jar. That is also what the comment in your sample code says. See https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/getResource for  a complete runnable sample - the build shell script shows how the jar file is built and executed.

Comment: One is an absolute url, the other is a relative one, using your class as the base location.  This is why everyone should have at least a fundamental understanding of web-age protocols.

Comment: @paulsm4 Hi, I have a different scenario with regards to output. Both ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt) and Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) giving me SUCCESS when run in Eclipse. But both of them returning NULL when run from a executable jar on windows machine. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @mannedear
One thing that I've noticed, when running from IDE, they are case-insensitive (both subDir/readMe.txt and subdir/readme.txt are same), however, when running from jar, they are case-sensitive (subDir/readMe.txt and subdir/readme.txt are different).