# Java/Eclipse - getClass().getResource(...) is returning null

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, bufferedimage, getresource

When executing following code, **imgURL** is always set to **NULL**:

```
try {
    URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("assets/image.png");
    System.out.println(imgURL);
    BufferedImage sheet = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Image failed to load.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Assets is a source folder, and is listed under "Project>Properties>Java Build Path". I have also tried to clean the project and rebuild. Additionally, adding a "/" before "assets" does not work and would not fulfill my purposes anyways.

This is a previous version of the code which worked in eclipse, but not as an executable Jar:

```
BufferedImage sheet = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/image.png"));
```

I simply don't understand why **imgURL** is being set to **NULL** in the first place, as the predominant answer online is to use the exact syntax as in the first code block. This has also been implicated for use in executable JAR files, which my project will require for thorough testing.

Any help you can give will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** My problem has been solved thanks to [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind) and [ingrid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901721/ingrid). As it turns out, when using getClass().getResource(filename), I needed to be using the file name without the relative path (assets/filename).

Comment: Try `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(name)` Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269556/strange-behavior-of-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource-in-executa

Comment: Try URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("image.png");

Comment: I see, when using this method, there is no need to add "assets/" before the file name. Thanks a ton!