# Get text file from properties directory in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have:

a JSP-file called `index.jsp` which contains the following code:

```
<%
    JSONVerschillendeTalen jsonVerschillendeTalen = JSONVerschillendeTalen.getInstance();
    JSONObject algemeenJSON = null;
    JSONObject indexJSON = null;
    try {
        indexJSON = jsonVerschillendeTalen.getJSONObject(request, "Index.txt");
        algemeenJSON = jsonVerschillendeTalen.getJSONObject(request, "Algemeen.txt");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

And a class called `JSONVerschillendeTalen` which contains the following code:

```
public class JSONVerschillendeTalen {

    private static JSONVerschillendeTalen jsonVerschillendeTalen = new JSONVerschillendeTalen();
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    public static JSONVerschillendeTalen getInstance() {
        return jsonVerschillendeTalen;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONObject(HttpServletRequest req, String bestandsnaam) throws IOException, ParseException {
        return (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("NL/" + bestandsnaam).getPath().replaceAll("%20", " ")));
    }

    private JSONVerschillendeTalen() {

    }

}
```

Whenever I run the code in the `index.jsp` file in a normal class (for testing), it works. When I run the same code in the jsp file, it doesn't. Does anybody know why?

[Properties directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHbTN.png)

Comment: avoid using java codes in jsp page

Comment: I know, but if someone goes to a link manually which ends on .jsp, then the page doesn't contain any text because the JSON files contain the text for the webpage.

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Comment: NullPointerException. the `.getResource("NL/" + bestandsnaam)` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getClass().getResource()` instead of `getClass(). getClassLoader().getResource()`. The second method search resource relatively to `ClassLoader` root, which highly likely differs from your sources directory in web container.

Following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269556/strange-behavior-of-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource-in-executa/13292358#13292358) has a very good explanation of difference between both.