# Images not found when exporting to runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, imageicon

In my application I'm having two packages of which one contains the .class files and in the other one the pictures are stored. Almost all of the images are used on or as buttons.

So at the moment the project's structure looks like this:

[image: project]

I initialize those buttons like this and when launching in Eclipse everything's working fine:

```
btnRegisterBack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Gui.class.getResource("/resources/back.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
```

As I've already been looking through (as it feels for me at the moment) all stackoverflow articles dealing with this topic and tried almost everything mentioned there effortless.

What I've tried so far is of course checking Build Path but so far everything should be included I guess (would've liked to give you an image of it here so you can check this but stackoverflow said I need at least 10 reputation for more than 2 links).

Other than this I had the images at first stored next to the .class files in the same package as them (that was the starting point), then tried to solve the problem moving the pictures first to the "resources"-package (as seen above) and then to a new folder as suggested in this post: stackoverflow. com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images.

After all these attempts wouldn't work I just had a look into the .jar-file to check if the images have even been exported. They're stored directly in the .jar in a "resources"-folder which is on a different path than the .class-files:

[image: resources]

So what I thought could help was refering to the images by giving the path "backwards" like

```
btnRegisterBack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Gui.class.getResource("/../../../resources/back.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
```

as they're stored in a different directory. I've been trying different amounts of steps to the folders above and also tried if there's a difference between "/../", "/./", "../", "./" but so far the only thing that changed was that the program now also doesn't work in Eclipse anymore unless I return to the "old path" ("/resources/back.png").

The last thing I tried was using a "retrieveImage" method which uses a URL from java.net as someone else on Stack Overflow suggested but this also didn't solve any of the problems.

This is for a university assignment.

Comment: Your file is named `Back.png`, not `back.png`.

Comment: Check this topic, the answer may  help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617114/images-wont-appear-in-a-jar/44618386#44618386

Comment: @JB Nizet, I think I already checked that and Java doesn't make a difference if it's written with a capital letter or not but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @BalázsNemes, I just try to use what is written in this article but somehow my Eclipse doesn't recognize ImagIO.read as it's telling me "ImageIO.read cannot be resolved to a type. Any suggestions on this? :/

Edit: Just copy-pasted the code from the article you linked instead of typing it myself, now it's working

Comment: @BalázsNemes thank you soooooo so so so much, thanks, that totally worked after some tweaking, I owe you so much, I don't know what I shall say right now, I'm so happy it's working