# Using ImageIcon to access a picture, can't access it, how to fix?

Tags: image, swing, file, jframe, imageicon

I am using ImageIcon to access a photo I have cropped. I put all the cropped pictures in a pic source folder in side the project. Yet when I try to use this.getClass().getResource("image 2.png") to find the image 2.png photo, the code couldn't find it. Is there anyway to fix this, do I have to re upload all the picture into a different folder?

the "image 2.png" is inside the pic source folder, which is within the folder of the project Alle, according to the navigator panel on the right. (I am using eclipse)

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class alle extends JFrame {

     JButton button1, button2;
     JLabel Label1, Label2;
     ImageIcon Icon1;
     ImageIcon Icon2;

    public alle() {
         setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3)); //create a gridwolrd like thing that's like 2 row, 3 column
         button1 = new JButton("set");
         add(button1);
         Label1 = new JLabel(" button");
         add(Label1);
         Icon1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/alle/pic/image 2.png")) ;
         JLabel p = new JLabel(Icon1);
         add(p);
    }

    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        alle adfc = new alle();
        adfc.setResizable(false);
        adfc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        adfc.setVisible(true);
        adfc.pack();
        File f = new File ("/alle/pic/image 2.png");
        System.out.print(f.exists());}}
```

Comment: If pic is a source folder, and image 2.png is in that folder, then it's in the root package. So the path should be `/image 2.png`. Also, I don't want to be rude, but you should really learn the basics first, like indenting your code properly and consistently, respecting the Java naming conventions.

Comment: thanks, I will indent it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of problem about a year ago. You should be able to resolve it by writing a loader method for retrieving the images. You can find a detailed answer on this article which also worked for me: [Images Won't Appear In A Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617114/images-wont-appear-in-a-jar/44618386#44618386)

If you don't want to read through the whole post here's the code sample that should resolve things, you only need to adjust it to your needs:

```
public ImageIcon loadIcon(String iconName) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(loader.getResourceAsStream(iconName));
    return new ImageIcon(icon);
}
```

From this method you should be able to retrieve your images. I hope this helps you.